# How to block url when the user has not verified their account ? (Symfony 6)

Tags: authentication, symfony

For my project (Symfony 6) I want to restrict some url as long as the user has not validated his account by clicking on the link received by email.
Because since i have make Registration (with symfony's website) I don't understand the interest of this point (account isVerified)

How to do this?

i've tried many things like modify security.yaml

Comment: Please share more details. Usually, there's some field on your user entity responsible for that verification. Why not check that field, either on login or on the route you want to secure?

Comment: Because i want to restrict many urls via security.yaml (globally) and i dont know how to do this with isVerified() function

Comment: Why not use an additional role for that, or Symfony's expression language?

Comment: Because im beginner in Symfony and i dont know how to this. I know how to set a role but not to add a newer. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can give the user an additional role when they verify, then deny access if they don't have it in your controller like so:

```php
// src/Controller/AdminController.php
// ...

public function adminDashboard(): Response
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_VERIFIED');

    // or add an optional message - seen by developers
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_VERIFIED', null, 'User tried to access a page without having ROLE_VERIFIED');
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code

You can also deny an entire pattern in security.yml:

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    access_control:
        # matches /users/verfied/*
        - { path: '^/users/verfied', roles: ROLE_VERIFIED}

        # matches /users/* except for anything matching the above rule
        - { path: '^/users', roles: ROLE_USER }
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-url-patterns-access-control